# A question in elementary differential geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, hamiltonian-mechanics

Let $M$ be a finite dimensional manifold of constant curvature $\kappa$. Consider a solution of the Hamilton--Jacobi equation
$$ \partial_t u + |\nabla u|^2 = 0. $$
Can we give a precise estimate of a modulus of semi-concavity, that is an estimate of the form
$$ D^2 u_t \leq \lambda_t \mbox{id} ? $$
In case $\kappa=0$, we have
$$ \lambda_t \leq \frac{C}{t}, $$
an estimate which does not depend on the initial function $u_0$.
We will be however interested in the case where $\kappa<0$.

Comment: Will the following formula be correct? It involves a sectional curvature. $$ D^2 (\frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2) [\xi,\xi] = (\nabla u \cdot \nabla D^2u)[\xi,\xi] + |D^2u \xi|^2 + R(\nabla u,\xi, \nabla u, \xi). $$